# Create folders whose name matches the filename in Python

Tags: python, filenames

I have a folder comprising video (.avi format) files. For each video file I want to create a dedicated folder whose name is the same as the video file. Is there a way to do this in Python?  Currently, I know how to generate a folder for each file, but I am struggling to name the folder.

```
len_videos_folder = len(glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/videos_folder/*.avi'))

for x in range(len_videos_folder):
  pathlib.Path("/content/drive/MyDrive/frames_folder/folder%d" %x).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
import os

files = os.listdir("text_files")
print(files)

for i in files:
    baseName = os.path.splitext(i)[0]
    os.mkdir(f"text_files\\{baseName}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- Read all file names in folder to list
- Create folders based on list items

import os

```
import os.path
import glob
fpath = r"C:\Nanda\videos\*"

folder_list=(glob.glob(fpath))

folder_list = [w.replace('.', '_') for w in folder_list]

for folder in folder_list:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(fpath,str(folder)))
```

In my case

[image: output]

Comment: Useful, thank you!  I have chosen Kirito's answer as the correct one.